# Moving some graphics around the frame

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, animate

I tried to animate some graphics (e.g. the letter A) from a point of the frame (e.g. the center) to another (e.g. the north-west corner).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{animate}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Animation}
  \begin{animateinline}[autoplay]{20}
        \multiframe{30}{i=0+1}{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay] 
        \node at ($(current page.center)!{\i/31}!(current page.north west)$){A};
        \end{tikzpicture}}
    \end{animateinline}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Obviously, the previous code does not work since "Content of first frame must not have zero width". Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Do you actually need the tikzpicture to be zero width? Otherwise you could simply remove the `overlay` option.

Comment: The example is almost what I need, I need to move something from the centre to the frametitle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`animate`-made animations run in a PDF Widget that "floats" on top of the normal page content. The animation frames determine the size of this widget which should be non-zero in x and y, obviously. However, the "`overlay, remember picture`" option makes the `tikzpicture` and thus the animation frames zero-size. Hence the error.

To fix this, the `tikzpicture` could be made as big as a slide and put into the slide background. (However, it will still float on top in the PDF viewer.)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{animate}

\begin{document}

\AtBeginShipoutNext{%
  \AtBeginShipoutUpperLeft{%
    \unitlength=\paperheight%
    \put(0,-1){%
      \begin{animateinline}[autoplay]{30}
        \multiframe{31}{i=0+1}{
          \begin{tikzpicture}[x=\paperwidth,y=\paperheight]
            \useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
            \node at ($(0.5,0.5)!{\i/30}!(0,1)$){A};
          \end{tikzpicture}
        }
      \end{animateinline}%
    }%
  }%
}%

\begin{frame}{Animation}
  % add "normal" content here.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```